# Why do I get `bitcoind: command not found` in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, bitcoind

I have built the bitcoin source on my Ubuntu desktop, and have installed the proper libraries via apt-get and building some.

When I do:

```
cd src
bitcoind -daemon
```

I get the error:

```
bitcoind: command not found
```

and when I do `./bitcoin` I get:

```
bash: ./bitcoin: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Go to the directory with the `bitcoind` binary.

Make sure it's executable:
`chmod +x bitcoind`

Now run it:
`./bitcoind -daemon`

Answer (score 6):

Also, if you want to just run `bitcoind` (without `./bitcoind`), add it to your executable path:

1. As Andrew [mentioned](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/474/why-do-i-get-bitcoind-command-not-found-in-ubuntu/475#475), first be sure to **`chmod +x bitcoind`** in your `src` directory.
2. Still in the `src` directory, run **`pwd`** to get the full path (for example `/home/alex/src`)
3. Add it to your .profile with **`echo "export PATH=$PATH:/home/alex/src" >> ~/.profile`**

Now you can execute `bitcoind` from anywhere in your system when logged with your user.

Answer (score 0):

I put this line in my `/home/chris/.bashrc` file:

```
alias bc='/home/chris/src/bitcoin/src/bitcoind'
```

Then (after starting a new terminal) I can type just `bc` instead of `bitcoind`.  There's no need to edit your PATH variable if you use an alias like this.

You'll need to change the `/home/chris/src/bitcoin/src/bitcoind` bit to match the correct location of the `bitcoind` executable on your system.

It's also OK to do this:

```
alias bitcoind='/home/chris/src/bitcoin/src/bitcoind'
```

if you want to type `bitcoind` out in full to run it.  It may look like a recursive definition, but it's fine.

Comment: Note that `alias`es only work at an interactive prompt and do not work inside shell scripts.